# Set time out for a session or transaction in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, timeout, settimeout

Below is my scenario:
My application begins a transaction, inserts/updates and then calls a web service. There is a possibility that the web service takes long to process the request. Is there any way to configure a time out for my session/ transaction in my hibernate layer so that i can gracefully close the session. 
P.S. - Alternatively i can also look to configure a time out for my web service call.Assume that i dont have that liberty. Is there anything i can do in Hibernate or do i need to write my own custom logic (using threads join constructs) to implement these

Answer (score 3):

You can [set timeout](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout%28int%29) at the level of particular query or if you use JPA's EntityManager you can add [query hint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215).

The theory is that Hibernate uses by default optimistic locking (if database transaction isolation level conforms to that), so records are never locked againts writes or reads. As a result, even long lasting transaction should not hurt performance badly.

If you are using pesimistic lock, you can set timeout for them in Hibernate Session. Look at [Session.LockRequest](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.LockRequest.html).

Comment: set time out and query hint wouldnt work in my case because my insert or update query would get executed but i cant commit the tran because the web service call has not returned.LockRequest solves another purpose where i m trying to fetch a row which is locked due to update from another tran